# Some missed file for gdbm on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gdbm

I want to write a program based on GBDM on ubuntu. I Installed ubuntu, gcc and make.

After installing (Os, gcc, make), I search for any files related to gdbm (*.a, *.so, *.h), and I saw only the  following files:

```
/usr/share/doc/libgdbm-compat4
/usr/share/doc/libgdbm6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm_compat.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm_compat.so.4.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so.6.0.0
```

I manually, created soft link for

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so
```

as

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so
```

But I could not find any gdbm.h(or related .h), so I downloaded sample gdbm.h (however I could get it from installing gdbm-dev or etc).

My  questions is:

1- Is it normal that there exists library file (libgdbm.so.6) but there doesn't exists related header file?

2- What is the best (or popular) way for solving this problem!

Comment: You shouldn't be manually creating symlinks within `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Linux distributions (including Debian and Ubuntu) have separate packages for the compiled software and its development headers (as those headers are often not needed). For Debian/Ubuntu there is a convention to name the package containing the development files with a `-dev` suffix.

In your case, your required files (including `libgdbm.so` and `gdbm.h`) are contained in the [libgdbm-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libgdbm-dev) package. You can install it with

```bash
apt-get install libgdbm-dev
```

You can find packages containing a certain file with a search on https://packages.ubuntu.com/#search_contents